# How do I return arbitrary JSON objects to a jQuery Autocomplete list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

#### jQuery part:

I have a jQuery UI 1.8 Autocomplete form that fetches remote JSON data from a Rails controller.

```
$('input#test').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
      $.getJSON(
        "<%= find_stuff_url(:format => :json) %>",
        request,
        function(data){
          console.log(data);
          function(data) {
            $.map(data, function(item) {
            return {
              "label" : item.control_point.label,
              "value" : item.control_point.geonames_uri
            }
            });
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        // ...
    }
  });
```

#### … what I get returned:

This Rails controller just returns an array of `Objects` (actually, `ActiveRecord` instances), serialized into JSON. I would like to use this data to populate the Autocomplete list. Right now, what I receive is an array of serialized ActiveRecord objects – for example one of these objects could be:

```
Object
  control_point: Object
    geonames_uri: "http://sws.geonames.org/5128581/"
    label: "New York (US)"
    lat: "40.7142691"
    lng: "-74.0059729"
    map_id: 1
    name: "New York City"
```

#### What I need:

However, jQuery Autocomplete *probably* wants a JSON array of objects that carry `id` and `label` to populate its list — yet I don't have these. This is [what the documentation says](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/):

> A response callback, which expects a single argument to contain the data to suggest to the user. This data […] can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data (String-Array or Object-Array with label/value/both properties).

I don't quite understand what's meant by "String-Array or Object-Array with label/value/both" properties.

In this example, my output would be a list of those `control_point` Objects, shown like:

```
label: "New York (US)", value: <the geonames_uri>
label: "New York (Somewhere else)", value: <another geonames_uri>
…
```

I tried to adapt the code from the documentation using `$.map`, but it doesn't seem to work (i.e. the autocomplete shows nothing).

**How do I pass an arbitrary JSON object to jQuery Autocomplete, so it shows a list of results? More explicitly: What do I have to put in `function(data){}`?**

Comment: Erm, what values do you want to be autocompleted? you don't just pass a whole block of different kind of values to it.. Is it the label? is it the name?

Comment: @DvirAzulay Sorry, had to be more clear: Yes, for example, the `label` property should be shown to the user, and for example, `geonames_uri` could be the actual value behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation (at the same link you posted) explains what is meant by the terms String-Array and Object-Array:

> The local data can be a simple Array of Strings, or it contains
>   Objects for each item in the array, with either a label or value
>   property or both. The label property is displayed in the suggestion
>   menu. The value will be inserted into the input element after the user
>   selected something from the menu. If just one property is specified,
>   it will be used for both, eg. if you provide only value-properties,
>   the value will also be used as the label.

So at the end of the day, it's either a String-Array: `["value1", "value2", ...]` or an Object-Array:

```
[
  { label:"First Value", value:"value1" },
  { label:"Second Value", value:"value2" },
  ...
]
```

You can choose to either make the required server side changes to serialise the data to look appropriate, or `map` it client side, as in [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp). Either way the end result should be one of the above formats.

So, for example, something like this:

```
function(data) {
response( $.map(data, function(item) {
  return {
  "label" : item.control_point.label,
  "value" : item.control_point.geonames_uri
  }
}));
```

Comment: That JSONP example gave me a rough idea, and copy/pasting the JSONP code works. When trying to adapt it (see edited question above), still nothing happens. What could I be missing?

Comment: @david: That's very true, you could to this client-side. However, there are two good reasons to do it server-side: 1) to keep the amount of data over the line low and 2) to prevent exposing possibly sensitive data (user_id, updated_at, etc).

Comment: @slhck, your example isn't correct. Autocomplete gives you a `response` object you need to call with the data. You're just creating a new function but not calling `response` with your `$.map` result.

Comment: @PPvG, (2) is presumptuous and seems irrelevant here, and (1) is true although not necessarily the only factor in a decision. You're assuming you know way more than you do (e.g. Cost of changing the server code vs. paying for extra bandwidth). You don't even know if the OP has control over the server-side...

Comment: I got it to work, thank you. I thought `response` wasn't needed and it would just return. Added my (preliminary) working code to your answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @slhck, a pleasure. Haha, this is the first time someone has added their own code to my answer :) I don't mind at all.

Comment: @david: Well... you're free to your opinion. No need to be rude. While it's true that the server-side code might not be under the OP's control, he never mentioned such a restriction in his question. Regarding point (2), you might be right. I like to be on the paranoid side of caution. If feel, however, that point (1) is perfectly valid. Bandwidth cost and speed might not be of concern on the server side, but don't tell me that you really think reducing the amount of data **every** user has to download **every** time they use this autocomplete is not a good idea.

Comment: @PPvG You certainly have a point. I probably wasn't clear enough in saying that I didn't necessarily want to change the server code, but the focus of the question was never on the Rails side. This is a development work-in-progress. We will eventually have to decide this when other factors come into play. Right now, it's just (1) a way for me to learn Javascript and (2) not such a huge issue. Good to have alternatives though.

Comment: @PPvG, never intended on being rude, my apologies. All I'm saying is those are decisions you cannot make because you aren't privy to the necessary context required to make an informed decision. In particular, if an application is intended for 200 people (say, the staff of a particular department on a local network), then even if you make the word "every" very big and bold (not trying to be rude, saying it with a smile) the difference is a few kB of data every few days. Which brings us back to the point that we aren't in a position to make that decision.

Comment: @david: you're right, I'm assuming too much. I'm pretty new here; I guess I still have some things to learn!

Answer (score 2):

This is something you'll want to do server-side, i.e. in Ruby on Rails. You could to this:

- Give your model (ActiveRecord entity, whatever) a method `toAutocompleteResult` that returns an `Object` with just the label and value properties.
- In your controller (`return_stuff_url`?), loop through your result set, call `toAutocompleteResult()` on them and put the results in an Array of sorts.
- Convert the Array to JSON and return it.

I'm not a RoR developer, so I can't give you specific code. But this should be pretty easy to do in any OO language.

Edit: by the way, a JSON string array looks like this:

```
["String 1", "String 2", "String 3"]
```

And a JSON Object array would look like this:

```
[
    { "label" : "Label 1", "value": "Value 1" },
    { "label" : "Label 2", "value": "Value 2" }
]
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about changing the Rails side. That would have been the path of least resistance. But I'd like to do it in Javascript only, if possible.

Comment: In that case remapping the data, as @david pointed out, is your way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this on the server

```
def my_autocomplete_controller_method
  q = params[:term]
  records = Record.find_by_whatever q
  records.map { |record| {label: record.your_label, value: record.your_value} }
end
```

On the client (coffescript):

```
$find_field.autocomplete
   source: /path_to_controller_method
```